# How do I use CiviDiscount for an event?

Tags: cividiscount

I want to apply a CiviDiscount to an event that uses a Price Set, but it doesn't seem to work the way I want.

The Administer CiviDiscount / New Discount Code form includes 2 fields ...

- 'Events'
- 'Price Field options'

The on-screen help for the Price Field options says 'If your form uses a price set, the discount will be applied to all options in the set by default. However, if you want the discount to be applied only to specific price options - select those options here.'

The implication is that I can just specify the Events for which I want the code to be valid.

But that's not how it works. I can only get the Discount Code to work if I specify both the Event and the Price Field. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Looking at the CiviDiscount code, the discount is only applied to all Price Field options if the Price Set has 'is_quick_config' set to TRUE. These are the Price Sets that are created directly from the Event or Contribution page form, and not from Manage Price Sets.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. What version of Civi and the discount extension are you running? In an older version of the discount extension (2.1) you could specify each price set that you want the discount to be applicable to. But it seems the newest, 3.0, is much simpler and you only pick event.

Comment: I'm using CiviCRM 4.6.3 and CiviDiscount 3.0.

Comment: Hmm, I am also running 4.6.3 and civiDiscount 3.0 and I don't have the price field options. In my experience with the old discount module, when you could specify by price set, yes, you had to select each item in the price set you wanted to apply your discount to. Not sure if this helps, wish we could request to throw the module on the demo site to put us on the same page.